A reverse turkish fill?

This is my first puzzle here. I just came up with it recently, so its a bit rough around the edges. Please excuse the awkwardness.

Umm... I think I'm mishearing my friends.
Jakub from Nitra told me "when I turned the corner, my kids yelled taboos." But
his children are too young to know any taboos.
Birnir from Reykjavik told his date that she "looked like a hernia model." But
she looked beautiful to me.
Siti from Kuching made sense at least. She just said "I need you to commit to
party tonight." But I can't party until I figure this out!
I guess that is why Ivan from Lviv asked me "are you new here" while looking
around. That's pretty rude considering he was on the phone.
Tamar from Tel Aviv said she would go to the party, but was so violent. She told
me "I will go kill you first".
Before I could react, Yusuf from Istanbul blurted out that "the horse is
testable that's good for the party, right?" I have no idea what horse he's
talking about.
Just when I thought it couldn't get any worse, Hachi from Taipei dropped an
n-word! Something along the lines of "Sorry I'm late, it was hard to get a cab
because there were so many n- passengers already." They're just a typical
butcher, not some racist nutjob.
It didn't seem to phase Chun from Hong Kong though, he just asked "are your
gametes cured?" What kind of question is that?
Seriously. What, were my friends thinking?
Hint #1:

 Focus on what language each of my friends is likely to speak natively. Despite speaking English, they are all doing something in their native language that is causing my confusion.

Hint #2:

 Turns out that I am also guilty in this question of the same linguistic phenomenon that I misheard in my friends. It just wasn't as noticed because it was in English (and in a less awkward position).

Hint #3:

 The answer is hinted in at least 3 ways. The title, a pseudo-acrostic, and the actual mishearings themselves. It is a single word.

Hint #4: (big hint, nearly trivializes the puzzle)

 all of the knowledge needed is found on this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)


We proceed according to hint 4
Nitra (Slovakia) "when I turned the corner, my kids yelled taboos"

 "Ta is a filler typical of Eastern Slovak" (so instead of taboos it's probably just "bus")

Reykjavik (Iceland) "looked like a hernia model"

  "a common filler is hérna ("here")"

Kuching (Malaysia) "I need you to commit to party tonight."

 "speakers often use words and phrases such as ... itu ("that") as common fillers" so it's just "I need you to come to party tonight"

Lviv (Ukraine) "are you new here"

 "ну (nu, "well")" so it's just "are you here"

Tel Aviv (Israel, Hebrew) "I will go kill you first"

 "Millennials and the younger Generation X speakers commonly use כאילו‎ (ke'ilu, the Hebrew version of "like")" so it's just "I will go first"

Istanbul (Turkey) "the horse is testable that's good for the party, right"

 "işte ("that is")" so it's "the horse stable that's good for the party, right"(?) (still sounds weird)

Taiwan (Taiwanese Mandarin) "n-word"

 那個 (那个）（nei4 ge4) which literally means "that", but is often just a filler word, source: https://www.digmandarin.com/confusing-chinese-n-word.html

Hong Kong (Cantonese) "are your gametes cured?"

 removing "噉 gam2 ("so; then")" gives "are your meats cured"


You are exactly correct with the Taiwan answer. I think I may have made an actual mistake with the cantonese one: rot13(V fnj tnz3 nf fbhaqvat yvxr "tnz" ohg vg znl fbhaq zber yvxr "xna" creuncf?)

Close enough that I'll mark it solved. I may have gone too far with the acrostic, it made the choice of fills a bit forced. rot13(Gur gvgyr vf n ersrerapr gb gur ghexvfu şrl juvpu erirefrf gb lrf. Rnpu "sevraq" svyyf jvgu n jbeq gung fgnegf jvgu bar bs gur yrggref bs GUVAXVAT. Gur dhrfgvba "Jung, jrer zl sevraqf guvaxvat?" vagragvbanyyl unf gur pbzzn fhpu gung gur nafjre vf fvzcyl "lrf".)

Thank you for filling in the rest of the intended solution. I like the idea behind the puzzle, but the linguistic and cultural knowledge needed to naturally place them (and thus read them back) is significant and difficult to learn from a single source.
